# Photoshop CC 2017 - Combine Shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2017

I'm trying to combine two rectangles and Subtract it form front shape. No way I can do it as shown below.
[image] **Combine Shapes** and **Subtract Front Shape** both options are not active. Anybody please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Hi. These aren't shape layers.  They are smart objects.

Comment: @BillyKerr So, what should I do?

Comment: Just draw two shapes instead, then combine those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers shown in your screenshot are smart objects. The combine shape functions only work on shape layers.

So, draw a square instead using the Rectangle tool, rotate it, and squish it to a diamond shape using the Move Tool

Duplicate this shape layer, and move the duplicate down a little using the move tool.

Select both layers, and do *Layer > Combine Shapes > Subtract Front Shape*

[image]

Here's the result

[image]